# SOQL error index out of bound : 0

Tags: apex, soql, list

I get this error if **LargestRevision** returns null. ie., fields revision and quote link have no values. Why isn't the **else** part handling null values? Following is the code I tried.

```
   if(quoteLink.Quote_Link__c!=null)
   LargestRevision=[SELECT Revision_Number__c FROM OPP_QuoteLink__c WHERE Quote_Link__c=:quoteLink.Quote_Link__c ORDER BY Revision_Number__c DESC LIMIT 1];      
      
      if(LargestRevision.size()!=null){
          clonedQuteLink.Revision_Number__c=LargestRevision.get(0).Revision_Number__c+1;
          clonedQuteLink.Quote_Link__c = quoteLink.Quote_Link__c;                
      }
      else
      {
          clonedQuteLink.Revision_Number__c=1;
          clonedQuteLink.Quote_Link__c = quoteLink.Id;                
      }
```

Here

> Revision_Number__c is a number field.
>
> Quote_Link__c is a lookup field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LargestRevision.size()` will never return `null`.

The `size()` method will return `0` if the list is empty.

From the [documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_list.htm):

> **size()**
>   Returns the number of elements in the list.
>
> **Signature**
>   `public Integer size()`
>
> **Return Value**
>   Type: Integer
>
> **Example**
>
> ```
> List<Integer> myList = new List<Integer>();
> Integer size = myList.size();
> system.assertEquals(size, 0);
>
> List<Integer> myList2 = new Integer[6];
> Integer size2 = myList2.size();
> system.assertEquals(size2, 6);
> ```

Changing to the following should resolve this:

```
if(LargestRevision.size() > 0) {
    clonedQuteLink.Revision_Number__c=LargestRevision.get(0).Revision_Number__c+1;
    clonedQuteLink.Quote_Link__c = quoteLink.Quote_Link__c;                
}
```

Comment: I get Attempt to de-reference a null object as ERROR

Comment: @MnZ What type is `LargestRevision`? If it's a `List` then that should not be possible, if it's an `SObject` you should be getting `no rows to assign to SObject` as your error. Are you sure you are getting that error on the lines you've posted above?

Comment: LargestRevision is a list.

Comment: @MnZ Can you add the full error you're getting and the line it refers to in your question? Based on the information you've given so far there is no part of your code that should give you that error (assuming you've made the changes I've suggested correctly).

Comment: ERROR is List index out of bounds: 0 Error is in expression for the line:           clonedQuteLink.Revision_Number__c=LargestRevision.get(0).Revision_Number__c+1;

Comment: @MnZ if you change `LargestRevision.size()!=null` to `LargestRevision.size() > 0` like I suggested in my answer then you shouldn't get this error, have you done this?

Comment: yes I don't get the error any more. It seems there is a problem with my logic. Thanks for the heads up. I will accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should replace the first part of the if with

```
 if(LargestRevision!=null and LargestRevision.size()!=0){
      clonedQuteLink.Revision_Number__c=LargestRevision.get(0).Revision_Number__c+1;
      clonedQuteLink.Quote_Link__c = quoteLink.Quote_Link__c;                
  }
```

because if LargestRevision is null (no values found) then you cannot call .size() on a null